# UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8> to [UInt8] without memory copy

Tags: swift, pointers

Is it possible to create a `[UInt8]` from an `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>` without copying the bytes?

In the `NSData` world I could simply call

```
let data = NSData(bytesNoCopy: p, length: n, freeWhenDone: false)
```

and just wrap the pointer.

Comment: I think you can do something like `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(ptr, count: *the number of elements here*)` which can then be made to an array. With Swift 2 you probably don't even need to make an array out of it, since almost all methods apply to the BufferPointer as well

Comment: @ago When it's made into an array, do the bytes get copied?

Comment: Arrays have an initializer for UnsafeMutableBufferPointers so I'm farily certain that the bytes don't get xopied. If you're unsure, just do a test with loads of data and check it with Instruments

Comment: I meant when the UnsafeMutableBufferPointer is converted to the [UInt8], are the bytes copied?  It appears so.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, you can create an 
`UnsafeMutableBufferPointer` from the pointer:

```
let a = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: p, count: n)
```

This does *not* copy the data, which means that *you* have to ensure that
the pointed-to data is valid as long as `a` is used. 
Unsafe (mutable) buffer pointers have similar access methods like arrays,
such as subscripting:

```
for i in 0 ..< a.count {
    print(a[i])
}
```

or enumeration:

```
for elem in a {
    print(elem)
}
```

You can create a "real" array from the buffer pointer with

```
let b = Array(a)
```

but this will copy the data.

Here is a complete example demonstrating the above statements:

```
func test(_ p : UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>, _ n : Int) {

    // Mutable buffer pointer from data:
    let a = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: p, count: n)
    // Array from mutable buffer pointer
    let b = Array(a)

    // Modify the given data:
    p[2] = 17

    // Printing elements of a shows the modified data: 1, 2, 17, 4
    for elem in a {
        print(elem)
    }

    // Printing b shows the orignal (copied) data: 1, 2, 3, 4
    print(b)

}

var bytes : [UInt8] = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
test(&bytes, bytes.count)
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a workaround and for the thorough example. It doesn't exaclty answer my original question of having a toll-free conversion from UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8> to [UInt8]. But perhaps there is no way without memory copy.

Comment: @tidwall: I am pretty sure that there is no way. Swift Array manages its own backing store for the elements.

Comment: Thanks to the anonymous downvoter, who reminded me to update the code for Swift 3/4 :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UnsafeBufferPointer` + `map` to  achieve your goal.
KEEP IN MIND: pointer boundary should be maintained by yourself, while arrays will  do by itself
`let bytesArray = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: bts, count: bytes.count).map{$0}`
**Swift 5, Xcode 11**:

```
var bytes: [UInt8] = [1, 3, 5, 7]
let count = bytes.count
print(bytes)

// MARK: - [UInt8] -> UnsafePointer<UInt8>

// producing dangling pointer warning bug?
let bts1: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = UnsafePointer(bytes)
print(bts1, bts1[0], bts1[1], bts1[2], bts1[3], bts1[4])

let bts = withUnsafePointer(to: &bytes[0]) {
    $0.withMemoryRebound(to: UInt8.self, capacity: count) { $0 }
}
print(bts, bts[0], bts[1], bts[4])

// MARK: - UnsafePointer<UInt8> -> [UInt8]
let bytesArray = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: bts, count: bytes.count).map{$0}
print(bytesArray, bytesArray[0], bytesArray[1]/*, bytesArray[4]*/)
```

output:

```
[1, 3, 5, 7]
0x0000600001946840 1 3 5 7 0
0x0000600001946840 1 3 0
[1, 3, 5, 7] 1 3
```

bad samples:

```
/// invalid sample 1
let testA = withUnsafePointer(to: &bytes) {
    $0.withMemoryRebound(to: UInt8.self, capacity: count) { $0 }
}
print(testA, testA[0], testA[1], testA[4])

/// invalid sample 2
let testB = withUnsafePointer(to: bytes[0]) {
    $0.withMemoryRebound(to: UInt8.self, capacity: count) { $0 }
}
print(testB, testB[0], testB[1], testB[4])
```

output:

```
0x0000000102b4f520 32 104 0
0x00007ffeed203ac0 192 58 254
```