# Automatically convert UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint> to [CGPoint] in Swift

Tags: objective-c, arrays, swift, core-graphics

I am getting a `UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>` that points to an array of one or two elements, I would like to build a Swift function converting `UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>` to `CGPoint` that wouldn't require me to specify the expected size of the array, is it possible ?

Thank you

Comment: No. In contrast to UnsafeMutableBufferPointer (compare e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31106427/unsafemutablepointeruint8-to-uint8-without-memory-copy), UnsafeMutablePointer is just a pointer (quite similar to a C pointer) and does not have any information about the number of elements that it points to.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you ! So the only solution is to know the size in advance ?

Comment: Yes. UnsafeMutablePointer is just a memory address, nothing more.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a code context that yields you `UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>` and that could be redone.